# How can I update the Account Name field for a contact using the data import wizard?

Tags: account, contact, update, data-import-wizard

I'm trying to do bulk update/inserts using the data import wizard, and everything seems to work except that the "account name" field will not be populated when the data is imported. New contacts created through the wizard will not have anything in the Account Name field, and contacts that are updated will not have the field affected. I have a column in my import CSV for the Account ID for the accounts for each contact, and when importing, I map that field to Contact: Account ID. However the Account Name field never updates. What could the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

Jack, please check:

1. The CSV file for the contacts contains a field called 'AccountName'.
2. Check that this field is mapped correctly by the wizard. If you are
   using'AccountName' it will automatically mapped for you. If using a different name, you can map it yourself.
   [image]
3. Verify that the value of the AccountName field is a real account in your org. If the AccountName is bad, the field won't be imported.
4. Verify success in: Setup->Monitor->Jobs->Bulk Data Load Jobs>[Your job]->ViewResults.